# How to convert slope-intercept form into parametric form

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

$Y = 2x+1$

$Z = 4x$

how to convert to the parametric form ?

Comment: Are these two separate equations or is this a system of two equations?

Comment: This appears to be almost in parametric form already, except that you'd probably want to write $x(t) = t; y(t) = 2t + 1; z(t) = 4t$, so that $t$ is the parameter.

Comment: @StackTD It is one equation

Comment: If you mean it's _one system_ (of two equations); then it is already parametrized in $x$... Introduce $x=t$ if this makes the parametrization clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $y$ and $z$ in terms of $x=t$. You will find $x(t)=t$, $y(t)=2t+1$ and $z(t)=4t$. Then write $$t\mapsto(t,2t+1,4t)$$ that is the parametric form of a line, namely the line passing through the point $P=(0,1,0)$ with direction given by the vector $\vec{v}=\langle1,2,4\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks, That is the answer but I didn't understand how you got it, could you please expand   your explanation ?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by saying Write y and z in terms of x = t

Comment: You have y and z already written in terms of x. You can use x as parameter and call it as parameters are usually written: t or s. You can still use x as name it doesn’t matter. But given that x can be whatever you want this make it as parameter. Then you can parametrize you sistem of equations (line) as a point + vector. The point is found setting t=0 while the vector is found reading the coefficients of t.

Comment: How did you get to x = t, if that wasn't it, I'm thinking if it was a more complex problem, without zeros and ones.

Comment: @hjx x is not explicitly given and so it can be whatever you want and I choose to call it t...